# Building multiple Gradle projects in Jenkins with AWS CodePipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, gradle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Gradle project that consists of a master project and 2 others that included using `includeFlat` directive. Each of these 3 projects has its own repo on GitHub. To build it I checkout all 3 projects into a common top folder then `cd` into the master project and run `gradle build`. And it works great!

Now I need to deploy the resulting app to AWS EB (Elastic Beanstalk) which is also works great when I produce the artifact locally and then deploy it manually. I want to automate the process so I'm trying to set it up using CodePipelines + Jenkins as described in [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-four-stage-pipeline.html) adjusted for Gradle.

The problem is that if I specify 3 Sources in the pipe I end up with my projects extracted on top of each other creating a mess in Jenkins workspace. I need to somehow configure each project to be output to its own directory within Jenkins workspace and I just don't see a way to do it (at least in UI)

Then, of course even if I achieve what I want I need somehow to `cd` into the master directory to run `gradle build` and again I'm not sure how to do that

P.S. Great suggestions from @Phil but unfortunately is seems that CodePipeline [does not currently support](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248267) Git submodules or subtrees

Comment: Could you not use something like git submodules? https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules

Comment: Interesting idea though I much prefer to have a flat project structure

Comment: But don't you already have separate repos for each project? You could create another parent project that includes them all into their own directories as sub-modules and use that one for your build

Comment: So the problem is I have no control over how CodePipeline calls `git clone` and I get empty folders for my submodules. There's a `--recursive` switch but how to apply it? P.S. doen't look good https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248267

Comment: Link back to the same question on AWS forums https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=265274

Comment: I don't know AWS at all so I'm not sure but is there no way to execute an arbitrary command as part of the build, ie `git submodule update --init`?

Comment: From what I understand they pull the code with "fetch" or something like that so .git folder is actually missing from the set they pull. I guess I can have some dummy github project just to kick off the gradle script and have gradle pull the code. Will try that

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but could you ignore/delete the sources passed via Pipeline and do the multiple `git clone` from within your Jenkins instance via a bash command step?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm referring to in my last comment

Answer (score 0):

I would start common build, when changes happened on any of 3 repos. With say 5 minutes delay, to have single build, even if changes are introduced to more then one repo.

I can't see good way to deal with deployment in other way than using `eb deploy`... old way... Please install aws tools at your jenkins machine. Create deployment job triggered on successful build. And put bash script doing deployment there. Please put more details about your deployment, that way I can help with deployment script.

Comment: Jenkins is already running on EC2. I'm not clear where you are going with this? I think I stated my problem clearly enough: 3 GitHub projects, 1 master, 2 subprojects (includeFlat). I think what you are proposing is pretty much what I describe in my comment to the main post: have a trigger on the projects involved, ignore the initial code and do scm from the gradle script (bash in your case). At this point it's not worth the trouble for me, unfortunately

Comment: On your jenkins install aws tools, with `eb` utility. Create job which will deploy your artifact. Or in  other way - do on jenkis what you are doing manually. Perhaps with scripts, not in aws console, but that is just different tool.